# Robotic arm fall to ground in gazebo

Tags: ros, robotics, gazebo-simu, rviz, urdf

I create a custom URDF in Solidworks and simulate it in ROS when ever I launch the robot in the gazebo simulator the arm fall to the ground. the robot is perfectly fine in rviz.
[image: left rviz simulator the one is right gazebo simulator]

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are not sending any signals to the joints, so it is behaving as links connected to a movable joint that is not powered. You need to:

Define the joints as fixed joints as

```
    <joint name="footprint" type="fixed" >
        <parent link="base_footprint" />
        <child link="base_link" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
```

or add a `controller` to your system as described [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/44481/controlling-joints-in-gazebo/).

Follow the [Gazebo ROS Control](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros) to add those to your system and be able to interact with your joints via the `joint_state_publisher` topic.